# Parse.com Subclass ParseUser

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a `ParseUser` subclass:

```
@ParseClassName("_User")
public class PUser extends ParseUser implements AppUser {

   public PUser() {
   }

   Some custom getters here....

}
```

And I have `Event` class:

```
@ParseClassName("Event")
public class Event extends ParseObject {

   public Event() {
   }

   public List<PUser> getHosts() {
      return getList("hostedBy");
   }

   Some custom getters here....

}
```

Problem is that `getHosts()` method return list of ParseUser and when I'm trying to loop.

```
for (PUser user : users) {
   if (user.getObjectId().equals(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId())) {
      return true;
   }
}
```

I get `ClassCastException`.

What is the correct way to subclass `ParseUser`?

Comment: Both classes are registered in Application class

Comment: A shot in the dark. What happens if you do @ParseClassName("User") instead, or perhaps remove it completely. I think maybe that the call to register might capture the fact that it is extending ParseUser without it.

Comment: cYrixmorten, I tried to remove it. It does not help.

Comment: Ok 1) please post your logcat and 2) 'hostedBy' contains an array of pointers to ParseUsers right?

Comment: Right, logcat says java ClassCastException